# iPad OpenGL animating texture vs uiimageview

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, opengl-es, uiimageview

I have a sequence of 24 images that I need to animate on the iPad. The images are full screen - 1024x768.

I currently have them displayed using an UIImageView, however there are some issues

If I use [UIImage initWithContentsOfFile] to load my images, then the sequence displays very slowly the first time they are displayed, but smoothly after this.

If I use [UIImage imageNamed] to load my images, the sequence plays smoothly every time, but I have memory errors.

Is there a better solution? Can I somehow integrate an OpenGL animated texture on a layer? Can I reload my images while still using inintWithContentsOfFile?

The Elements application for the iPad has fast loading large animation, and this is based on Cocos2D. Is there a way to use elements of this in a normal uikit app?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: looking for a similar solution for my iphone app, did you ever get it solved?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't, time was running tight so we just canned this element of the project. It might be worth looking into Cocos2D and see what it can do. Elements does do large interactive image sequences so perhaps there is a solution there.

Do let me know if you find anything!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820701/how-to-animate-big-images-in-ios/26905046#26905046